Combinatorial interpretation of the probability of a set of restricted partitions
Let $A$ be a set with $|A| = 2k$ and let $B$ be a subset of $A$ with $|B|=n \leq k$. Let $P_2$ be the set of all partitions of $A$ consisting of blocks of size 2. That is $P \in P_2$ provided $P$ is a partition of $A$ and for all $X \in P$, $|X|=2.$
Additionally, we call a partition $P \in P_2$ good if for all $X \in P$, $X \not \subset B$.
I am looking for an explanation on how to directly count that the probability of a partition in $P_2$ being good is $$\frac{2^n {k\choose n} }{{2k}\choose{n}}.$$
I arrived at this result by trying to count the number of ways of seeding a round of 1 versus 1 competitions of people from set $A$ under the restriction that members of set $B$ cannot play each other. I just don't know how to interpret this result in that context.
To verify that this number is accurate consider that $$|P_2 | = \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{i=1}^{k} {{2(k-i+1)}\choose 2} = \frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}.$$
To count the good partitions we have $n! {2k-n \choose n}$ ways to choose a partner for the elements of set $B$ from $A\setminus B$. Then $\frac{(2k-2n)!}{(k-n)!2^{k-n}}$ ways to choose the remaining blocks.
It's straight forward to check that $$\frac{n! {2k-n \choose n} \frac{(2k-2n)!}{(k-n)!2^{k-n}}}{\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}} = \frac{2^n {k\choose n} }{{2k}\choose{n}}.$$

See a solution here (found using formula searching tool approach0). See also here.

@JeanMarie Thanks! How do you access that tool?

By typing this or (without prior formula) that
